# How to extract google search displayed answer data from google maps, using python?

Tags: python

I have a large spread sheet with 3 columns. Start, Destination, Distance (needs to be filled). Instead of doing it manually, I was thinking I will take out the data from a google search result.

So I'd send a google search request for each cell in the spread sheet and append the highlighted part in to the third column. I don't need help with that, I am just wondering how to get the data that I need out as in the distance.

[image]

Here is the sample code for finding the temperature in a city for example

```
import requests 
import bs4 
  
# Taking thecity name as an input from the user
city = "Imphal"
  
# Generating the url  
url = "https://google.com/search?q=weather+in+" + city
  
# Sending HTTP request 
request_result = requests.get( url )
  
# Pulling HTTP data from internet 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup( request_result.text 
                         , "html.parser" )
  
# Finding temperature in Celsius.
# The temperature is stored inside the class "BNeawe". 
temp = soup.find( "div" , class_='BNeawe' ).text 
    
print( temp )
```

I am going for something like that but I don't know which argument to pass into the soup.find() method.

Typing,

```
$('html body#gsr.srp.vasq.wf-b div#main.main div#cnt.big div#rcnt.GyAeWb div.D6j0vc div#center_col div#res.eqAnXb div#search div div#rso div.ULSxyf div.GguUuf div#lud-ed.yf div div.g div.ULktNd.rQUFld.rrecc div#lud-dsu div.vk_c.IPbEu div div#lud-search.yf div div div div#exp0.ytJVH.rreh div.mGSxre.Ra9ql div.lMmzdb div.BbbuR.uc9Qxb.uE1RRc span.UdvAnf').innerText
```

Into the browser console prints out what I am looking to take out, but I am not entirely sure how to get that using bs4.

Answer: The code for the temperature example, works with other forms of answers too. Coincidentally, all the text on the answer box is pulled out. You just need to send a generic google search url, not the one for weather.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML structure and class names are the same For any new request?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the code, the html is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the source code you are downloading using `request_result = requests.get( url )`  is the same of  as what you see in the browser?

I think that it is  the cookies request page.

But  if the page is what you need ,  that it has inside the class "UdvAnf"  , you can find all span with class you need.

In this way:

```
temp = soup.find_all("span" , {"class":"UdvAnf"})
print( temp )
```

output:

```
[<span class="UdvAnf"><span class="iQIYjb myy6W">16 min</span> (<span>14,5 km</span>) </span>]
```